# Reportportal integration working with Stable Karate Version 0.9.5?

Tags: junit4, karate, reportportal

We are trying to integrate ReportPortal with Karate 0.9.5 with Junit 4 Runner. Does the current ReportPortal agent-java-karate supports Karate 0.9.5 ? does anyone manage to use the following agent and got it working with karate 0.9.x version ?

https://github.com/ogarashchuk/agent-java-karate-0.9.3

Comment: seems to be old and not maintained. refer this thread for DIY solutions: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/619